# What does "cancel endorsement" mean on the back of a check?

Tags: check, endorsement, signature

I had some property damage to my house and upon receiving a check from my insurance company it is addressed to both myself and my mortgage company.  I signed the check and mailed it to my mortgage company.  I received the check back WITH a signature from a manager at the mortgage company; however, there is a stamp over my original signature stating "cancel endorsement".  I've never seen this before, and I'm not sure what it means.  Am I still able to deposit the check?

Comment: Strictly guessing, but I'd think they didn't want to handle a check that was as good as cash, so they "cancelled" your previous endorsement. If that's right, they'd have preferred that you simply send them the original check without your signature; they'd endorse it, and send it back to you to do with as you pleased. If it was me, I'd just endorse it again and deposit it.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, while it obviously is a guess I can't imagine them mailing it back without cancelling the endorsement.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to the mortgage company regarding how to proceed.

My bank was the mortgage company so they wouldn't complete the deposit until I actually had the repair done and we provided proof.